# Trigger fake error 105

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way to make my page look like it doesn't exist if a unique URL query not given. Can't find any solution. I've tried a PHP's trigger_error function, but it can't trigger

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

I could include not existing domain, but lol, it's not impossible. I am looking to do this in PHP, so I'm looking to know if that's possible at all. Or maybe someone can suggest a working solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I simply want my site appear like it doesn't exist, for example this non existing URL: http://gwwrgrewg.com/ . But when I enter my query to the url, my content will appear, example http://gwwrgrewg.com/?uniquequery

Answer (score -1):

If the URL query is not given, you should the 'user' redirect to a custom 404 page or a diffrent error page

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but it seems you haven't understood what I need.